# Get latest records by two column in a query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named 'reports' as below:

```
id     company    year    quarter
1      A          2008    1
2      A          2008    2
3      A          2008    3
4      A          2008    4
5      A          2009    1
6      A          2009    2
7      B          2008    1
8      B          2008    2
9      B          2008    3
10     B          2008    4
11     B          2009    1
12     B          2009    2
```

The table contains year and quarter. Each year has four quarters. The latest record is determined by year and quarter column. So the record with highest year and highest quarter in that year is the latest record.
I would like to get the latest report for each company in a single query. In this example, this would be the result.

```
id     company    year    quarter
6      A          2009    2
12     B          2009    2
```

I have tried to achieve it by using following query:

```
select * from reports
inner join ( select company, max( year ) AS year, max( quarter ) AS quarter 
             from reports group by company ) as r 
    on r.company = reports.company 
        and r.year = reports.year 
        and r.quarter = reports.quarter
```

Comment: and what is your current query? Its not that we do requests.. You supply, we improve.

Comment: thing `group by` , max

Comment: Your sub-query returns unrelated year/month values. Consider table data (c1, 2017, 4), (c1, 2018, 2), will return (c1, 2018, 4)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pre-MySQL 8 way uses a subquery to identify the latest records for each company:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT company, MAX(year + quarter / 4.0) AS max_year
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY company
) t2
    ON t1.company = t2.company AND
       (t1.year + t1.quarter / 4.0) = t2.max_year;
```

[image]

### Demo

Your current attempt has a problem, because it will find the max value for `quarter` without regard to the particular year.  That is, it would find a max quarter of `4` for both companies, even though in their latest respective years (`2009`), the max quarters were actually 2.  I get around this by forming a decimal year, which can be, e.g. `2009.5` for the second quarter of `2009`.

Beginning with MySQL 8+ we can take advantage of the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function:

```
SELECT id, company, year, quarter
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY company
        ORDER BY year DESC, quarter DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1;
```

### Demo

Comment: Thank you! the first one did the job. I haven't tried the second one yet since I am not using mysql 8.

Answer (score 0):

use co-related subquery

```
    select year, company,max(id),max(quarter) from reports t
   where t.year in ( 
      select max(year)
     from reports t1 
    where t1.company=t.company 
        group by t1.company
                   )
                   group by year,company
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do:

```
select t.*
from t
where (t.year, t.quarter) = (select t2.year, t2.quarter
                             from t t2
                             where t2.company = t.company
                             order by t2.year desc, t2.quarter desc
                             limit 1
                            );
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/MDGM55512) is a rextester.

I cannot think of a simpler way to accomplish this.  And with an index on `(company, year, quarter)`, this should have better performance than alternatives.